# How to transform an high def PDF to low def using command line tools?

Tags: macos, unix, pdf, ghostscript

I've a unix server (mac osx in fact) which transform actually PS files to PDF files. It does this through `ps2pdf`, with those parameters:

```
 ps2pdf14 \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
   -dEPSCrop \
   -dColorImageResolution=72 \
   -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
    INPUT_FILE \
    OUTPUT_FILE
```

But now I've to adapt this script to have a PDF file as input instead as PS.

So I guess that ps2pdf will not work anymore, and I need something which can reduce the quality of the pdf.

Do you know a tool like this?

Comment: If I've a problem when creating a java program, it has to do with bash, so if I've an issue creating a bash program, it has to do with bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ps2pdf14` script just runs the `ps2pdfwr` script with `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4`, which in turn uses `gs` with various parameters.  You can examine that script to see the options.

You could run `gs` directly, putting in the various options added by the scripts and your own `-d` options (which are passed directly to `gs`).  I.e. try:

```
 gs \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
   -dEPSCrop \
   -dColorImageResolution=72 \
   -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
   -q \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=OUTPUT_FILE \
    INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: I've found exactly the same result! Thank you!

Comment: Look, no bash involved in the solution either. It doesn't matter whether that command is invoked from bash, sh, or maybe directly by some other process.

Answer (score 2):

Your command should works with PDFs: Ghostscript (backend for ps2pdf) accept PDF as input file. I just tested ps2pdf from Ghostscript 9.04 and it works